# WPF Drag and drop image/label within lixbox wrappanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to make my image in the listxbox-wrappanel dragable, able to move the image within the canvas.

I've follow the sample at here, but still not working
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/442276/Drag-and-Drop-WPF-Controls

Below is my code:

XAML

```
<Canvas Name="canvastTable" Grid.Row="1" Margin="100,10,10,4" Panel.ZIndex="99" Background="Gold" AllowDrop="True" MouseMove="canvastTable_MouseMove">
            <ListBox Name="lbTable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="267" BorderBrush="White" Background="Green" BorderThickness="2" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="889" Panel.ZIndex="9999" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
            Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="C:\img\mcd.jpg" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10" Cursor="Hand" AllowDrop="True" 
                            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="lbTable_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="lbTable_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" AllowDrop="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </Canvas>
```

Code behind:

```
double FirstXPos, FirstYPos;
        object MovingObject;

        private void lbTable_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            FirstXPos = e.GetPosition(sender as Control).X;
            FirstYPos = e.GetPosition(sender as Control).Y;
            MovingObject = sender;

            MessageBox.Show("click");
        }

        private void lbTable_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MovingObject = null;
            MessageBox.Show("up");
        }

        private void canvastTable_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                (MovingObject as FrameworkElement).SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,
                                        e.GetPosition((MovingObject as FrameworkElement).Parent as FrameworkElement).X - FirstXPos);

                (MovingObject as FrameworkElement).SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty,
                        e.GetPosition((MovingObject as FrameworkElement).Parent as FrameworkElement).Y - FirstYPos);

                MessageBox.Show("move");
            }

        }
```

Comment: I did this a long time ago, perhaps can help you: https://github.com/gusmanb/DragPage

Comment: @Gusman I cant compile your file, it require windows 8.1. I still using windows 7 & visual studio 2013, can you convert to windows 7 compatible version.